# TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str, which part it refers to?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am a total beginner of python, may bring some basic questions here. Could someone please help?

I want to get the average for each student and then calculate the average of those averages. Get "TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str". Cannot figure out what it referring to and how to modify. Here is my code:

```
lloyd = {
    "name": "Lloyd",
    "homework": [90.0, 97.0, 75.0, 92.0],
    "quizzes": [88.0, 40.0, 94.0],
    "tests": [75.0, 90.0]
}
alice = {
    "name": "Alice",
    "homework": [100.0, 92.0, 98.0, 100.0],
    "quizzes": [82.0, 83.0, 91.0],
    "tests": [89.0, 97.0]
}
tyler = {
    "name": "Tyler",
    "homework": [0.0, 87.0, 75.0, 22.0],
    "quizzes": [0.0, 75.0, 78.0],
    "tests": [100.0, 100.0]
}


def average(numbers):
    total = sum(numbers)
    total = float(total)
    return total/len(numbers)


def get_average(student):
    homework = average(student["homework"])
    quizzes = average(student["quizzes"])
    tests = average(student["tests"])
    return 0.1*homework + 0.3*quizzes + 0.6*tests


def get_class_average(students):
    results = []
    for student in students:
        result = get_average(student)
        results.append(result)
    return average(results)

students = ["lloyd", "alice", "tyler"]
print get_class_average(students)
```

Comment: Have you read the traceback, which tells you exactly which line it's referring to?

Comment: Yes, I read that, but it list many lines. Always not for sure which line caused the problem.

Comment: Even if you don't fully understand it, you could at least include it. And to help interpret it: as a rule, start at the bottom, with the *last* line called before the error.

Comment: OK, thanks for the tips. :)

Answer (score 6):

When you enclose a name in quotes, it is a string literal, not a variable.

```
>>> x = 3
>>> x
3
>>> 'x'
'x'
```

Use `students = [lloyd, alice, tyler]` to refer to the variables you defined above.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out this.  I changed students list. But now it alarms: TypeError: 'float' object is not callable, which think it is the " total = float(total)".  So I quote it, still the same. And changed marks of every student into integer, doesn't work either.

Comment: @EmmaZhao - I ran your original code (with the change I specified) in my Python 2 interpreter and got `83.8666666667`. I can't reproduce your new issue.

Comment: Wow..weird, maybe it's the version thing, I will try to figure it out then.  Thanks a lot!